# What am I doing wrong here? DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Student learning DAX, Problem seems super simple but somethings just not going right.
Trying to separate orders into "Full Refund", "Partial Refund" and "No Refund".
But when there should be a "Full Refund" I can't get that to pick up.
I've tried simplifying it down to full or else, still cant get it right.

My DAX reads
refund amount = IF(SUM('Returns'[Refund Including Tax]) = sum('Sales'[Item Price]), "Full refund", "else").

Everything comes up "else" even though I know highlighted shouldn't.

Comment: image won't stay up on the post, but there are none showing as "Full Refund" and have it in table view so I can see which should be showing as full refund.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with SWITCH function in DAX

Write Calculated column as

```
Refund amount = SWITCH(TRUE(),
'Returns'[Refund Including Tax] = 'Sales'[Item Price], "Full Refund",
'Returns'[Refund Including Tax] < 'Sales'[Item Price], "Partial Refund",
"No Refund")
```

There should a relationship between Returns and Sales tables

Comment: Trying this but with SUM just gives me partial refund for all whether there was a refund or not.
Without SUM I just get an error message that it can't find a single value for column.

Thanks, but on this occasion hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of your Sales and Refund tables? Can a refund apply to more than one Sales invoice?

Comment: Sales table has each item as an individual row so multiple of the same order numbers showing (although obviously has gone through as one order). Refund table is the same. Given what I was taught and what Power BI has automatically picked up that's  given us a many : many.

Comment: What if you create a calculated column in each table [invoiceNo] & "-"&[ProductID]? Can you join on that? If that doesn't work, I may need a few records of data to figure it out.